# Using back/forward after AJAX link in rails app only shows partial

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails application, I've begun to tinker with AJAX for the first time and although I have it working wonderfully, it has one unusual behavior: Hitting back or forward after using an AJAX link will give you only the unrendered AJAX-pulled partial in plain text form.

How does one fix this? I can't find anything on Google pertaining to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any others with this problem, I found the culprit. There were a couple javascript links on the page with their hrefs set to `#` which messes with the browser's history when clicked. Replacing `#` with `javascript:void(0)` fixes the problem, giving the expected AJAX history behavior.